# List of directives and transclusion

Tags: angularjs, html, angularjs-directive, semantic-markup

I'm trying to build some navigation directives to isolate complexity. I want the following HTML to render my navigation:

```
<custom-nav>
    <nav-item>Item 1</nav-item>
    <nav-item>Item 2</nav-item>
    <nav-item>Item 3</nav-item>
</custom-nav>
```

If I wrote the directives right now, the resulting compiled HTML would look like this:

```
<custom-nav>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <nav-item><li><a>Item 1</a></li></nav-item>
            <nav-item><li><a>Item 2</a></li></nav-item>
            <nav-item><li><a>Item 3</a></li></nav-item>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</custom-nav>
```

however, this is invalid HTML (`<ul>`s can only have `<li>`s as children).

Without using `replace: true`, what is the best way for me to tackle this? The only things I can think of are:

1. Don't use `<ul>` or `<li>` - use aria roles to define my own list items.
2. Don't make the list semantically a list. I really don't want to do this.

Is there something I'm overlooking?

Comment: Replace is being deprecated in directives so I wouldn't use it if you can help it.

Comment: Just make directive replace base tag, nothing special here.

Comment: @MatthewGreen hence my question!

Comment: @dfsq, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood the issue correctly, but what I can say is,
you can pass the items you want to use as `li`, in an array, as a parameter to the directive, and loop over it in your link function to generate the recommended html result, that would remove any complexity related to the issue
please let me know if I misunderstood you.
Best of luck

Comment: That's not doing things "the angular way". That's maybe how you would want to do it with Angular 1.0 or 1.2 a year or two ago.